# Error message when connecting phone by USB "Unhandled error message:1.4213 was not provided by any .service files"

Tags: usb, 20.04

Previously I've never had any problems just connecting my Smartphone (Moto G7) to USB and then finding the files in "files". Today I get the error message "Unhandled error message:1.4213 was not provided by any .service files".

I may not have tried this since I updated from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

Comment: I get the same message when opening the Trash folder but on 20.10. 'nautilus -q' in the console helps me in my case.

Comment: @emvidi Thanks! This solved my problem.

Comment: @emvidi Thanks, worked for me too, Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 5):

Just to post this as an answer as I see that it does help some people.

Typing in a terminal `nautilus -q` resets the nautilus file manager from where these errors seems to come. It does not solve the problem but saves you from rebooting the pc and gives you the possibility to try again.

Comment: Works for nemo too! Finally!

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly.